# Exception: Invalid audio buffer size in some devices

Tags: android, exception, audio

I have an active app on the playstore and recently one smartphone encountered the following exception:
Invalid audio buffer size at
android.media.AudioTrack.audioBuffSizeCheck (AudioTrack.java:1151)

This is how my Audiotrack is created.

```
    val rate = AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
    val minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(rate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)

    val bufferSizes: IntArray = intArrayOf(1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768)
    var size = 0

    for(i in bufferSizes){
        if (i > minBufferSize){
            size = i
            break
        }
    }

    // if buffer read size fails
    if (minBufferSize < 0) {
        size = rate * 2
    }

    // Create audio track
    val audioTrack = AudioTrack(
        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, rate,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
        size, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM
    )
```

The above code works for 98% of the devices. But e.g. Galaxy J4 Core crashed at the audioBuffSizeCheck. Since I don't have this device available, I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: Possibly related: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/audio-latency#buffer-size

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll have a look into this :)

Comment: FWIW, the [Firebase test lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab) has a J1/J2/J7 available.